# When running a Excel add-in, I always get a error, if my previous run ended in a breakpoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, add-in, ribbon

I'm making a Ribbon add-in for the first time.

Sometimes I get this error/warning, when I run and start Excel from my VS10.

"`Excel experienced a serious problem with the 'exceladdin1' add-in. If you have seen this message multiple times, you should disable this add-in and check to see if an update is available. Do you want to disable this add-in?`" (I always answer no, but it's still pretty annoying)

The last couple of days I thought I got it somekind of randomly, but I did so ekstra tests before writing this question.

What I found was that I'll always get the error/warning, if my previous run hit a breakpoint.
I found it very strange, and it should't be like this right. Have anyone found a way to fix this?

Comment: Hehe, well, it was rather a serious mishap.  As far as Excel knows, your addin completely crashed it when you stopped debugging.  It did.  Don't forget about Edit+Continue support in the debugger.

Comment: @Hans Passant Yep. I underestimated Excel and it's ability to remember from time to time. Know I don't - thanks.
"Edit + Continue" you mean like the feature in the debugger where I can drag the debugger-line-arrow down to another line and such?

Comment: No, actually editing code after a breakpoint hit (Edit) and continuing executing after that without having to stop the program (+Continue).

Comment: Ah yes ofcourse. I know about it, but don't use it enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should get this message if you stop your debug session from within Visual Studio instead of closing excel. By stopping the session from VS, you kill excel, excel notices this upon next start and can even confirm that at the time your addin was running, therefore it recommends disabling it.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense. Actually I never tryed to close Excel first, because I could't continue from my breakpoint without an exception in VS. But I've outcomment that line now. And your right. If you Exit Excel in the normal way everything is fine.